# Can I monitor AWS EMR step failures using Cloudwatch?

Tags: monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-emr

In an EMR cluster, I run multiple Spark steps.

[image: Spark steps in EMR]

Steps may or may not have the same name.

I want to monitor the number of failed steps, grouped by the step name.

EMR triggers EventBridge events for a step status change, but I want numbers: the goal is to trigger an alarm if more than (say) 5 steps with the same name failed within (say) the last hour.

Was hoping to get a Cloudwatch metric counting failed steps, with a dimension of the step name. Can I achieve that?